# Sometimes Signalr was not loading properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application and for notifications I am using signalr.

In my Layout.cshtml page, I referenced the signalr in proper order as shown below

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js")"></script>
 @* Signalr part goes here *@
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Below was the code to start the connection

```
if ($.connection.broadcastHub) {
        $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function () {
        });
}
```

**Issue**

Now, everything working fine if signalr loads correctly but sometimes the signalr was not loading correctly as expected and it throwing the below error in console

[image]

If I refresh the page again(ctrl + F5) its loading correctly and working as expected but sometimes signalr throwing the above error and i am not able to resolve this issue.

I found similar question 
[SignalR: Sometimes Negotiating requests returns 404 error (Load-balanced)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140895/signalr-sometimes-negotiating-requests-returns-404-error-load-balanced) 
But, I am not doing anything with machine key in web.config and i dont know about anything regarding machine key

Please, can you provide your suggestions to resolve this issue. 
Thanks

Comment: do you put your js code in $(function(){...})?

Comment: so ,that is,when brower run js code,some js file not load complete

Comment: that makes sense to me, let me try and let you know

Comment: Now I think its working fine to me, Please provide your comment as a answer so that i will upvote it

Answer (score 2):

you should put you js code in a `$(function(){...})`
if not,when the js code run,some js file not load complete,so you got an error
and sometimes it's ok,sometimes it's error,sometimes it's may a diffrent error